# Unable to find the difference in these two OpenCV codes?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to learn OpenCV and i encounter these two code, the task of both code is same just to show the image but latter one doesn't work. I am using opencv 2.4.6 and visual studio 12

the second doesnt load the image but shows error saying no image found

```
 #include "cv.h"
 #include "highgui.h"
int main() // this code works
{
   IplImage* newImg;
   newImg = cvLoadImage("boxing.jpg", 1);
   cvNamedWindow("Window", 1);
   cvShowImage("Window", newImg);
   cvWaitKey(0);
   cvDestroyWindow("Window");
   cvReleaseImage(&newImg);
   return 0;
 }


#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
int main() // this code doesn't works
{
 Mat image;
 image = imread("boxing.jpg");
 namedWindow("original");
 imshow("original",image);
 cvWaitKey(5000);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: When adding an actual *question* to this, how about elaborating on what "doesn't work" *means*.

Comment: I mean to say that the image doesn't load in the second code..
if i use condition check then no image is printed out
    image = imread("boxing.jpg");
    if(!image.data) {cout<<"no image"; break;}
    else{
      namedWindow("original");
 imshow("original",image);}

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
using namespace cv;
```

after the `include` statements and before the `main` function.

**Why?**

All the OpenCV classes and functions are declared in the namespace `cv`. Or otherwise, you can also use the scope resolution operator like *cv::Mat*, `cv::imshow` etc to access the OpenCV functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix C functions with C++. While using OpenCv above 2.0 version (C++) you should call:

```
cv::WaitKey(5000);
```

as functions and classes starting with "cv" in names are obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

believe it or not, you've got a *linker* problem.

cvLoadImage() takes a char*, imread() a std::string. if you can't use the latter, it's due to some std/c++ lib wrongly linked.

please check extra carefully, if you're linking release libs against a debug build (or the other way round), 
if you accidentally changed the c-runtime (mutithreaded-dll).